# Is there a better class or library to use than ASyncTask for MySQL Requests?

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

I'm making an app with lots of ASyncTasks and it is getting quite strenuous and messy to create many many ASyncTasks for every single MySQL update, select, or other request I make. Is there a library or better class to use to make this process a lot easier?

Thank you!

Comment: use threads then, and manage them with thread pools.

Comment: you are confusing me. Are you using a Mysql Database or a local SQLite?
Anyway, why are you not creating one AsyncTask and pass the statement that you want to process?

Comment: @ChampS I am using a MySQL database on a server. The difficult part is that when I download data/SELECT from MySQL, I want it formatted into objects in the ASyncTask. That means that I have to create new ASyncTasks for every single type of select usage I need to implement. It's easy to create a single ASyncTask that just completes an action, but making it select something and format it into objects is the difficult part.

Comment: Why? As I said you can pass the command you want as an enum or something and in your asynctask you can decide what to do using a switch case. But without your code I can not really help you. Maybe you can show me an example.

Comment: More simply, I am asking if there is a library that would allow for easier requests to a MySQL server than having to create a whole class to complete the action. I would rather just have a method call that returns all the information I requested in the specified format (i.e. concatenated columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use network libraries like Volley, Retrofit or Ion for network operations. They have nicely handled it with executors and handlers. Plus they support gson data model mapping also so you can get direct objects from requests.